# determine clockwise or counterclockwise rotation between 2 lines

Tags: vba

I have a piece of code that takes 4 points (which makes up 2 lines), and determines the angle between them. How can I programmatically determine if this is a clockwise rotation or counter-clockwise rotation?

```
Private Function calculateAngleAlt(L1X1 As Double, L1Y1 As Double, L1X2 As Double, L1Y2 As Double, L2X1 As Double, L2Y1 As Double, L2X2 As Double, L2Y2 As Double) As Double
  line1A = L1X2 - L1X1
  line1B = L1Y2 - L1Y1
  line2A = L2X2 - L2X1
  line2B = L2Y2 - L2Y1
  lineDot = (line1A * line2A) + (line1B * line2B)
  distL1 = Abs(Sqr((line1A * line1A) + (line1B * line1B)))
  distL2 = Abs(Sqr((line2A * line2A) + (line2B * line2B)))
  calculateAngleAlt = ArcCos(lineDot /(distL1 * distL2))
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. A line could rotate in either direction and still end up at the same angle.

Comment: How does the angle between the two lines determine the rotation?

Comment: If I were to input 4 points, and it gave me an angle, how could I determine if that angle was clockwise or not?

Comment: That's true T_Bacon, but if I had the angle from 4 points, could I find the direction then?

Comment: How would you distinguish 180 degrees clockwise from 180 degrees ant-clockwise? Or *any other angle* ?  Unless you mean to call any angle >180 "anticlockwise" but that seems pretty arbitrary.